# Selenium: Trouble opening drop down menu in span

Tags: java, selenium, automation, testng

I've got trouble accessing a dropdown menu that's inside a span, can't even get it to open in the first place (only through a function that happened by accident.

I'm trying to click on the dropdown menu of this site: https://globaldata.pt/cart (you need to put something in the cart for it to appear, it's the one that changes the quantity).

I tried a lot of different selectors already, not sure if it's a selector related problem at this point. I also already tried select, doesn't work because it tells me it's a span.

Here is the relevant part of my code:

```
@FindBy(id = "quantity-selector")
private WebElement quantity_selector_cart;

public void setQuantity() {
    String initial_count = this.quantity_counter.getText();
      
            this.quantity_counter.click();



    //this.quantity_counter.isSelected();
    //driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

  /*  List<WebElement> quantity_values = driver.findElements(By.xpath("/html//select[@id='quantity-selector']"));
    for (WebElement qv : quantity_values) {
        if (qv.getText().equalsIgnoreCase("3"));
        {
            qv.click();
        }
    }*/


}
```

TestNG tells me the test passes, so I assume the click works somehow? The expected behavior is that it should stay open, so I can select something from the dropdown menu, which doesn't happen. Strangely it does happen when I add the code currently outcommented (the one which should click on an element with the value 3 inside the dropdown menu). I really don't get it, hope you can help me understand what I'm doing wrong.

EDIT: Here is the relevant part of the html code I think, I know it says "select class" at the relevant part, but it does get recognized as span by selenium and throws an error

```html
<div class="d-flex flex-lg-column align-items-end justify-content-between content-right" data-qa="quantity-selector-T8BLACK">
<div class="cart-quantity-selector" data-qa="component cart-quantity-selector">
<form name="cartChangeQuantityForm_T8BLACK" method="post" action="/cart/change/T8BLACK">
<div class="quantity-selector" data-qa="component quantity-selector">
<label class="d-none" for="quantity-selector">Cantidad</label>
<select class="    select form-control custom-select js-select-quantity
" data-qa="component select quantity quantity-selector" name='quantity' id='quantity-selector' onchange='this.form.submit();'>
<option value="1">
1
</option>
<option value="2">
2
</option>
<option value="3">
3
</option>
<option value="4">
4
</option>
<option value="5">
5
</option>
<option value="6" selected>
6
</option>
<option value="7">
7
</option>
<option value="8">
8
</option>
<option value="9">
9
</option>
<option value="10">
 10
</option>
<option value="11">
11
</option>
<option value="12">
12
</option>
<option value="13">
13
</option>
<option value="14">
14
</option>
<option value="15">
15
</option>
<option value="16">
16
</option>
</select>
</div>
<input type="hidden" value="T8BLACK" name="groupKey">
<input id="" name="cart_change_quantity_form[_token]" class="form-control" type="hidden" placeholder="" value="E16srgpDolEhlaJOhbkLypJxdbUObW4C7yjnZznQZbQ" />
</form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In HTML, the dropdowns are generally implemented either using the `<select>` tag or the `<input>` tag. In Selenium to perform the same operations on the dropdowns,  Selenium WebDrivers provides a class called  **`Select`** class.

**Select class of Selenium WebDriver  provides the following methods to select value:**

1. **selectByIndex :** This method selects the dropdown option by its index number.
2. **selectByValue :** This method selects the dropdown option by its value.
3. **selectByVisibleText :** This method selects the dropdown based on the dropdown text.

[image]

**Working solution:**

```
WebElement quantity_selector_cart = driver.findElement(By.id("quantity-selector"));
Select select = new Select(quantity_selector_cart);
select.selectByVisibleText("2");
//OR
select.selectByIndex(1);
//OR
select.selectByValue("2");
```

Comment: thanks so much, this works! I'm sure I tried this before, but i remember not checking it in combination with the id selector, maybe that was the problem